# What does "\u7cfb\u7edf\u7e41\u5fd9\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u540e\u518d\u8bd5\u3002" mean?

Tags: php

I post some parameters to a PHP page and return some message, looks like `\u7cfb\u7edf\u7e41\u5fd9\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u540e\u518d\u8bd5\u3002`, I don't know what that means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like that's Chinese text. Decoded, it looks like this:

> 系统繁忙，请稍后再试。

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) translates that as:

> System busy, please try again later.

Comment: to be more specific, each \u<four hexadecimal numbers> represents a unicode letter. The first is \u7cfb, so it's the letter in unicode position 7CFB: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7CFB/index.htm

Comment: Just to say how I got this, I went into a Python REPL and typed `print u"..."` where the `...` is the `\uXXXX` things.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
print u"\u7cfb\u7edf\u7e41\u5fd9\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u540e\u518d\u8bd5\u3002";

Comment: but print noting, I don't know why?

Comment: @Shamrocker: Python isn't Perl.

Answer (score 3):

It's encoded unicode.  There's a converter [here](http://people.w3.org/rishida/tools/conversion/).

Answer (score 0):

They seem to be hex encoded unicode characters. Languages such as c# and java use these types of encoding, but webapps normally use the &# decimal values for encoding. It could be part of a Sql Injection attack. If it is appearing as a querystring parameter.